# Qt correct way to show/display/raise window

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt4

Quite often I find that I need to show and bring a window to a front. For example when the user attempts to reload the same document I simply bring up the old one. To do this I have code like this:

```
widget->raise();
widget->activateWindow();
widget->showNormal();
```

It's starting to feel like I'm missing a shortcut function. Surely this type of behaviour is quite common. Is there some preferred function that will do all of the above and/or just do the right thing on each target OS?

---

Note: I've just noticed a defect, thus a special function is even more important now. If the window is minimized, `activateWindow` does not work.  This happens even if you reorder the above to `showNormal` first.

Comment: Yes, I've been through the docs a lot.  Each OS does something slightly different, thus I need several calls. My app is the current top-level window in this case, so it usually works.

Comment: Sounds like a bug it works fine for me in PySide. Hard to evaluate without a SSCCE that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Indeed it seems like a bug, `activateWindow()` alone works for me as well. Can you test this with a newer Qt version (say, 5.6 or 5.7)?

Answer (score 18):

this is a working "shortcut" :

```
widget->setWindowState(Qt::WindowActive) ;
```

You can couple it with the last `Qt::WindowState` of the window.
This notation is not very explicit though.

Comment: Unfortunately **raise()**, **showNormal()** - they both didn't work for me. But **setWindowState(Qt::WindowActive)** works fine on my case. Thanks...

Comment: Weird... this doesn't work for me, but `activateWindow()` does. Maybe this has been fixed in Qt 5.7?

Answer (score -3):

No need for such complication. This is enough :

```
widget->raise();
widget->show();
```

By the way, you can call `show()` once, and unless you `hide()` it, there are no needs to call `show()` again.

Comment: This does not restore a window that has been minimized.

Comment: Nor does it give focus to the window. Those both `activateWindow` and `showNormal` are still required.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y You didn't mention in your question that a window can be minimized

Comment: I could argue that the call to `showNormal` is a clear indication that the window could be minimized.