# How to pop up QMessageBox when the application is running in background?

Tags: c++, qt, messagebox

I've been working on a Qt C++ application that deals with video processing. It usually takes a long time so that user would start the process and minimize the window to wait.

Now I'm encountering the problem that user cannot be alerted when the process is finished. I can show a QMessageBox within the application in the foreground. However there is no message that can actively notify the user when he minimizes the application and works on other stuff.

This notification doesn't have to be a pop-up. It could even be blinking in the taskbar. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I appreciate every one's quick and detailed response. QMessageBox and QSystemTrayIcon are two possible solutions. I do partially solve my problem by the following code:

```
HWND hHandle = FindWindow(NULL,L"nameOfYourApplication");
FLASHWINFO pf;
pf.cbSize = sizeof(FLASHWINFO);
pf.hwnd = hHandle;
pf.dwFlags = FLASHW_TIMER|FLASHW_TRAY; // (or FLASHW_ALL to flash and if it is not minimized)
pf.uCount = 8;
pf.dwTimeout = 75;
FlashWindowEx(&pf);
```

This will flash the taskbar. Once again, thanks so much for every one involved in this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QSystemTrayIcon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSystemTrayIcon.html) to show the messagex from the taskbar tray.

Use method [QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#showMessage) to fire a notification.

And with [QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible(bool visible)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#visible-prop) you can show/hide the icon in the tray.

Use [QSystemTrayIcon::setIcon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#icon-prop) to setup required icon.

Comment: +1 for you, it can be a solution, but I posted answer which solves problem with hidden messagebox when app is hidden.

Comment: I use the same idea, however it is implemented with windows api instead of qt api. Thanks though! I don't have enough reputation to support your answer. I wish I have.

Answer (score 1):

Inside QMainWindow:

```
ShowWindow((HWND)this->winId(), SW_MINIMIZE);//#include <windows.h>
ShowWindow((HWND)this->winId(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
showMessageBox();
```

Answer (score 0):

`QSystemTrayIcon` is normal solution, but you should add new code, and many apps in trays can be annoying, so you should be sure that your app really need icon tray. And back to the original question:

If you use this:

```
QMessageBox::information(this,"title","text");
```

then your `QMessageBox` will be really hidden as your window, but when you use this:

```
qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
QMessageBox box;
box.setText("text");
box.exec();
```

Or this for example:

```
qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
QMessageBox *box = new QMessageBox(this);
box->setWindowTitle("title");
box->setText("text");
box->show();
```

Then you get this `QMessageBox` if your window is hidden or not.

Why we need `qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);`? By default, a Qt application closes when the last window is closed, so if you close this box but windows will be hidden, then app will be closed. With `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed` it will run normal.

Edit:

```
QMessageBox *box = new QMessageBox;
box->setWindowTitle("title");
box->setText("text");
box->show();
this->showNormal();
```

Comment: well, I'm not sure on 100% that modal call of QMessageBox when the app is minimized will be showed to the user and "actively notify" user. I think it will be needed to call additionally something like QWindow::raise() on MainWindow of the app.

Comment: @N1ghtLight I tested it, and it was normal, but I impoved my answer,with some useful thing. If you are interested in this, you can see it.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried on Win 8.1, but it doesn't work. Message box appears, but minimized application doesn't rise and doesn't actively notify user. Also it looks like, because you suggest to use setQuitOnLastWindowClose, you think that main application window is going to be hide, but author wrote that application is just minimized to the taskbar.

Comment: @N1ghtLight Sorry, I did't understand you. Of course, if window is minimized and you want show it, you should call `this->showNormal();` See my edit. Is it normal now?

Comment: Call of this->showNormal() doesn't help too. On what OS are you testing? On Windows 8.1 if I run last your code example, where your last code snippet is trigerred by QTimer after 5 seconds app is launch, then: 1. App window is opened. 2. I minimzed the app to the task bar and other apps windows are active now. 3. After 5 seconds my test app starts blinking in the task bar, but it's not opened, etc, I don't see the message, I need to click on it in task bar to see the message. Do you have some another behavior?

Comment: @N1ghtLight `timer->start(4000);` connected to `echo()` slot which contains same code. 1. App opened. 2. I minimize it, slot called and I get the box and window become normal, there is no any blinking, all works. Win 7, Qt 5.2.0

Comment: hmmm ... well, for me it doesn't work, and I was pretty sure that it doesn't work :) maybe, it depends on some circumstance or really on platform. Also from my experience any non usual usage of QMessageBox in cross platform app will bring some portion of headache :)

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817334/qt-correct-way-to-show-display-raise-window  ...

Comment: @N1ghtLight Do `widget->raise();`and  `widget->show();` works properly in your Windows? If so, I improve my answer with this code.

Comment: No, it doesn't work too for me, I've already tried... as you can see by link to another question any answer is not accepted. This is "black hole" in Qt :)

Comment: It actually doesn't solve the problem. It will show the window, however only if you are in the desktop. If you are in another application, the window is shown in the desktop.